# Symfony2 The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form

Tags: symfony, webforms, csrf

I have a form that keeps getting the "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form." I have been unable to find the cause.

I know it is something simple. any help would be appreciated.

In the controller I have this:

```
public function settingsAction()
{   
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    /* @var $user User */
        $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken();

    $settingsForm = $this->createForm(new SettingsFormType(), array($user));
    $billingForm = $this->createForm(new BillingFormType(), array($user));
    $accountForm = $this->createForm(new AccountFormType(), array($user));



        return $this->render('DeductrDeductrBundle:Settings:settings.html.twig', array(
                'settingsForm' => $settingsForm->createview(),'billingForm' => $billingForm->createview(),'accountForm' =>$accountForm->createview(),));
}

public function createAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationFormType('Deductr\UserBundle\Entity\User'));

    $form->bind($this->getRequest());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $user = $form->getData();

        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect('/settings');
    }
```

The .twig file has this:

```
{% extends 'DeductrDeductrBundle:Base:base.html.twig' %}


{% block body %}
<div name='personal' style="padding-left:25px; width:600px;">
<h5>Personal Information</h5>
{#src/Deductr/DeductrBundle/Resources/views/settings/settings.html.twig #}
<form action="{{ path('user_registration_create') }}" {{ form_enctype(settingsForm) }}" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(settingsForm) }}>

 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>

            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
        {{ form_widget(settingsForm.first_name, {'attr': {'class' : 'half'}}) }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{ form_widget(settingsForm.last_name, {'attr':    {'class' : 'half'}}) }}
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Company</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                {{ form_widget(settingsForm.company, {'attr': {'class' : 'half'}}) }}

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Address 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                {{ form_widget(settingsForm.address1, {'attr': {'class' : 'half'}}) }}

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Address 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                {{ form_widget(settingsForm.address2, {'attr': {'class' : 'half'}}) }}

            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <label for 'city'>City</label>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
                {{ form_widget(settingsForm.city, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for 'state'>State</label>
            <td>
                <label for 'zip'>Zip/Postal</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for 'phone'>Phone Number</label>
            </td>

        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                {{ form_widget(settingsForm.province, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ form_widget(settingsForm.postal_code, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ form_widget(settingsForm.phone, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>         
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="{{ 'submit'|trans({}, 'DeductrUserBundle') }}" /></td>
</tr>
 </table> 
 {{ form_row (settingsForm._token) }} 
</form>

</div>
<div id="billing" style="padding-left:25px; width:600px;">
<h5>Billing Information</h5>
<form action="" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(billingForm) }}>
    {{ form_row (billingForm._token) }}

 <table>
    <!--    <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>

            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
        {{ form_widget(billingForm.fname, {'attr': {'class' : 'half'}}) }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{ form_widget(billingForm.lname, {'attr': {'class' : 'half'}}) }}
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Address 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                {{ form_widget(billingForm.billingAddress1, {'attr': {'class' : 'half'}}) }}

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Address 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                {{ form_widget(billingForm.billingAddress2, {'attr': {'class' : 'half'}}) }}

            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <label for 'city'>City</label>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
                {{ form_widget(billingForm.billingCity, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for 'state'>State</label>
            <td>
                <label for 'zip'>Zip/Postal</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for 'phone'>Phone Number</label>
            </td>

        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                {{ form_widget(billingForm.billingState, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ form_widget(billingForm.billingZip, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ form_widget(billingForm.billingPhone, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}
            </td>

        </tr> -->
<tr>
    <td colspan='3'>
     <h5>Payment Information</h5>
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Expiration Date</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>{{ form_widget(billingForm.expMonth, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget(billingForm.expYear, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Credit Card Type</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>{{ form_widget(billingForm.ccType, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Credit Card Number</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>CVV</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>{{ form_widget(billingForm.cardNumber, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget(billingForm.cvv, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>         
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="{{ 'submit'|trans({}, 'DeductrUserBundle') }}" /></td>

</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>

</div>
<div id="account" style="padding-left:25px; width:600px;">
<h5>Account Information</h5>
<form action="" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(accountForm) }}>
    {{ form_row (accountForm._token) }}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>Email</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='3'>{{ form_widget(accountForm.email, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>Password</td>
        <td>Confirm Your Password</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_widget(accountForm.password, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>{{ form_widget(accountForm.confPass, {'attr': {'class': 'half'}}) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="{{ 'submit'|trans({}, 'DeductrUserBundle') }}" /></td>

</tr>
</table>
 </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 5):

If this is your entire form template, it's probably this:

```
<form action="{{ path('user_registration_create') }}" {{ form_enctype(settingsForm) }}" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(settingsForm) }}>
    {{ form_row (settingsForm._token) }}
```

make sure to include `form_rest(settingsForm)`

But also, why three forms on one page? If you are new to Symfony, try getting one form to work on a page first. You would - in your case, need three `form_rest`s - one per instance of each form I think.

Hard to tell without more code tbh.

Comment: Or use form_start(form) and form_end(form) in twig when it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing two different form types.

You're rendering form of type `SettingsFormType` and submitting it to `createAction` which creates form of type `RegistrationFormType`.

It is likely possible that form name is taken into account when CSRF token is being generated. That being said, your token is bound to be different and incorrect each time - no matter what ;)

Hope this sheds some light on your problem ;)

Comment: no luck there. I am getting frustrated with symfony and am ready to quit trying.

Comment: can you update your question with complete TWIG form? This problem seems rather weird :-/

Comment: I found the answer. Thanks for the help. you sent me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was not adding this:

```
/** 
 * Creates a new settungsUser entity. 
 * 
 * @Route("/settings/create", name="user_settings") 
 * @Method("POST") 
 * @Template("DeductrDeductrBundle:Settings:settings.html.twig")
 * 
 */
```

once I updated the path in the twig it worked.

thanks for  all the help.