# Error "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form" in Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, csrf-protection

## Problem

FOS user-bundle forms (login, register, ...) are working just fine, but not my own forms, giving me:

> The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form

While I am trying to create a resource under:

```
http://www.project.local/app_dev.php/developer/new
```

or even:

```
http://www.project.local/developer/new
```

## Environment

- OS X EL Capitan 64 bit
- Web Server:

  - Server: Apache 2.4.16
  - Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler (mod_php7)
  - Thread Safety: disabled
  - Document Root: `/Library/WebServer/Documents/project/web`
  - PHP: `7.1.2`
- Symfony: `3.2.*`
- CodeBase generated using

  - [`$ symfony new project`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html)
  - [`$ php app/console generate:doctrine:crud`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html)
- FOS user-bundle: `~2.0@dev`
- KNP menu-bundle: `^2.0`

**app/config/config.yml**

```
framework:
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:     { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"

    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes:
        - 'form/form_div_layout.html.twig'
```

**app/config/security.yml**

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
```

**DeveloperController**

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $developer = new Developer();
    $form = $this->createForm(DeveloperType::class, $developer);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($developer);
        $em->flush($developer);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('developer_show', array('id' => $developer->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('BackendBundle:Developer:new.html.twig', array(
        'developer' => $developer,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**DeveloperType**

```
class DeveloperType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('user');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Developer::class
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return 'backendbundle_developer';
    }
}
```

**Form - Template**

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
<button type="submit" name="{{ form.vars.name }}">Create</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

**Form - Generated**

The form has always the hidden `_token` input field **present**.

```
<form name="form_name" method="post" class="ui form">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_name[_token]" value="YefVvhSvvNTItjw7ayDFwFi4sdf_6oOvsQjnUu9X7cw">
    <button type="submit" name="form_name">Create</button>
</form>
```

(`form_name` equals `backendbundle_developer`)

## What did I do?

1. Googled for hours and read all similar questions on Stack Overflow including the above
2. Rechecked the file system permissions

   The `httpd` process is running under `_www` user, so:

   ```
   sudo chown -R _www var/
   sudo chmod -R 775 var/
   ```

   Session files are created and updated under `var/sessions/` successfully
3. Changed `app/config/config.yml` entry

   ```
   session:
       handler_id: session.handler.native_file
       save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
   ```

   to

   ```
   session:
       handler_id: session.handler.native_file
       save_path: ~
   ```

with no success at all.

## Similar questions

This is not a duplicate of these similar questions:

- [symfony2 CSRF invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442922/symfony2-csrf-invalid)
- [Symfony 3.0.1 CSRF token present but invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208299/symfony-3-0-1-csrf-token-present-but-invalid)
- [The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455780/the-csrf-token-is-invalid-please-try-to-resubmit-the-form)
- [Symfony2: The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154035/symfony2-the-csrf-token-is-invalid-please-try-to-resubmit-the-form)
- [Symfony2 The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980367/symfony2-the-csrf-token-is-invalid-please-try-to-resubmit-the-form)
- [“The CSRF token is invalid” error in symfony 2 even using form_rest(form) function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021154/the-csrf-token-is-invalid-error-in-symfony-2-even-using-form-restform-functi)
- [Symfony isValid False CSRF token is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721414/symfony-isvalid-false-csrf-token-is-invalid)
- [Symfony 2. CSRF token is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584358/symfony-2-csrf-token-is-invalid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this

```
<button type="submit" name="form_name">Create</button>
```

With this

```
<button type="submit" name="form_name[submit]">Create</button>
```